# Error with URL in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

it should be something simple, but I've spent the last two hours trying to fix this. This is on Django 1.7 and Python 2.7

I'm getting the following error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /

The included urlconf 'blog.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

which is being caused by this line in the template:

```
>> {% url 'referrals:confirm_referral' claimCode %} <<
```

when the following line is being executed within the view:

```
msg_plain = render_to_string('referrals/email/sendInvite.txt', emailVariables)
```

I've tried [reverse_lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) call within the dict, as well as lazy but that has not solved the problem.

Here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^confirm-referral/<confirm_code>[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$', views.confirmReferral, name='confirm_referral', ),
)
```

here is the relevant part of the code (in a separate file called jobs.py):

```
            emailVariables = {
                'commsPromoHeadline' : thisOfferClaim.linkedOffer.commsPromoHeadline,
                'commsPromoSubHeading' : thisOfferClaim.linkedOffer.commsPromoSubHeading,
                'commsInvitationShortMessage' : thisOfferClaim.linkedOffer.commsInvitationShortMessage,
                'commsInvitationLongMessage' : thisOfferClaim.linkedOffer.commsInvitationLongMessage,
                'commsOfferButtonText' : thisOfferClaim.linkedOffer.commsOfferButtonText,
                'commsBanner' : thisOfferClaim.linkedOffer.commsBanner,
                'claimCode' : thisRecipient.claimCode, 
                #'offerLink' : lazy('referrals:confirm_referral' + thisRecipient.claimCode), 
                #'offerLink' : reverse_lazy('referrals:confirm_referral'), 
                'sender': thisOfferClaim.sender,
                'recipient' : thisRecipient
                }
            msg_plain = render_to_string('referrals/email/sendInvite.txt', emailVariables)
            msg_html = render_to_string('referrals/email/sendInvite.html', emailVariables)
```

and finally, the following is an extract from the relevant template:

```
You can quickly join by clicking on the link below:
>> {% url 'referrals:confirm_referral' claimCode%} <<
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1:**
I have two lines commented out in the dict above.
When I uncomment

```
offerLink' : reverse_lazy('referrals:confirm_referral'),
```

I get the following as a returned value:

```
<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x0441F890>
```

I would have expected a string? Is this what is causing the problem?

**Update 2:**
My main urls.py below:

```
import os
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin

from wagtail.wagtailadmin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.wagtailsearch import urls as wagtailsearch_urls
from wagtail.wagtaildocs import urls as wagtaildocs_urls
from wagtail.wagtailcore import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.contrib.wagtailsitemaps.views import sitemap
#import debug_toolbar


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    url('^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html')),
    url(r'^', include('people.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('reviews.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('commerce.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^activities/', include('video.urls',namespace='activities')),
    url(r'^course/', include('video.urls',namespace='course-videos')),
    url(r'^refer/', include('referrals.urls',namespace='referrals')),
    url(r'^robots.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt', content_type='text/plain')),
    url(r'^', include('people.urls')),
    url(r'^mission-control/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^cms-admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^search/', include(wagtailsearch_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    url('^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap),
    url(r'^', include(wagtail_urls)),
)


if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL + 'video/', document_root=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'video'))
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL + 'images/', document_root=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images'))
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL + 'attachments/', document_root=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'attachments'))
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL + 'platform/', document_root=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'platform'))
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL + 'offer/', document_root=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'offer'))
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL + 'people/', document_root=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'people'))
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL + 'reward/', document_root=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'reward'))
```

**Update 3:**
I have moved everything into a view, but I'm still getting the same error. Code can be found below:

```
class sendReferralMail():
    ##########################################################
    # this job sends out emails who have been invited to 
    # participate in a referral scheme
    ##########################################################
    try:
        #try to get all outstanding claims that are linked to receipients with a status of "commsPending". also prefetch recipient details to minimise DB hits
        allOfferClaims = OfferClaim.objects.filter(recipient__status='commsPending').prefetch_related('recipient')
    except:
        allOfferClaims = None
    if allOfferClaims:
        for thisOfferClaim in allOfferClaims:
            #go through each recipient that we've already filtered on previously
            for thisRecipient in thisOfferClaim.recipient.all():
                if thisRecipient.status == 'commsPending':
                    #get offer-specific content that we should be sending them
                    emailVariables = {
                        'commsPromoHeadline' : thisOfferClaim.linkedOffer.commsPromoHeadline,
                        'commsPromoSubHeading' : thisOfferClaim.linkedOffer.commsPromoSubHeading,
                        'commsInvitationShortMessage' : thisOfferClaim.linkedOffer.commsInvitationShortMessage,
                        'commsInvitationLongMessage' : thisOfferClaim.linkedOffer.commsInvitationLongMessage,
                        'commsOfferButtonText' : thisOfferClaim.linkedOffer.commsOfferButtonText,
                        'commsBanner' : thisOfferClaim.linkedOffer.commsBanner,
                        'claimCode' : thisRecipient.claimCode, 
                        'domain' : Site.objects.get_current().domain,
                        'offerLink' : unicode(reverse_lazy('referrals:confirm_referral')), 
                        'full_url' : ''.join(['http://', Site.objects.get_current().domain, unicode(reverse_lazy('referrals:confirm_referral')), thisRecipient.claimCode]),
                        'sender': thisOfferClaim.sender,
                        'recipient' : thisRecipient
                        }
                    msg_plain = render_to_string('referrals/email/sendInvite.txt', emailVariables)
                    msg_html = render_to_string('referrals/email/sendInvite.html', emailVariables)
                    send_mail(
                        thisOfferClaim.linkedOffer.commsPromoHeadline,
                        msg_plain,
                        settings.REFERRAL_EMAIL_SENDER,
                        [thisRecipient.email],
                        html_message=msg_html,
                    )
```

Comment: Please show the main urls.py that includes this one.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - main urls.py now in update 2. thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 0):

Your named regular-expression group isn't in the right form, it should be in `(?P<name>pattern)` form:

```
r'^confirm-referral/<confirm_code>[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$'
```

should become:

```
r'^confirm-referral/(?P<confirm_code>[a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$'
```

where:

```
name = confirm_code
pattern = [a-zA-Z0-9]{8}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

Comment: thanks - good spot. I've updated it but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: make sure you are not including an empty urls.py file, in this case check if 'blog:urls' does have any patterns in it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the might be that you are rendering the template that contains the url tag before the url config has loaded.

Using `reverse_lazy` will not work in this case, if the template is rendered before Django has loaded the url config.

You can fix the problem by moving the `render_to_string` calls into the view itself.

Comment: can't this be achieved by setting the ``DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`` env var and calling ``django.setup()`` in the seperate file?

Comment: @HassenPy `django.setup()` is used in standalone scripts. The OP mentions his views, so I don't think it's useful in this case.

Comment: I've moved everything into the view (see update #3), however it's not it's still throwing the same errors when I try to access a page (The included urlconf 'blog.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.)
Offending line is            
    'offerLink' : unicode(reverse_lazy('referrals:confirm_referral')),

Comment: `class sendReferralMail` does not look like a view to me. It is a class, not a function, therefore all of the code is evaluated when the class is loaded, before the url config has loaded, causing the error. Why have you made it a class not a function? When do you expect it to run, and how will you run it?